# Failed to run the inference graph - what could be wrong?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to deploy a locally trained model. I followed all of the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/preparing-models) for model preparation and I managed to deploy it.

However when I try to get the predictions, the online prediction responds with 502 Server error and the batch prediction returns `('Failed to run the inference graph', 1)`

Is there a way to get a better error message to narrow down what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: With trial and error I found that I had a mistake in the format of the input I was sending. 
The 502 Server error seems to not be related to this.

Comment: The fix for the 502 server error is rolling out this week.

Comment: Although the rollout will take all week to complete, some users are reporting the error is already fixed for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicated it occurred when running the session for the inference graph. It might be possible to uncover what is be happening with some code to use the model locally. One way to test it is to create a small input dataset and feed it to the inference graph to check if you can run the session locally.

You may refer the *local_predict.py* in the *samples/mnist/deployable/* in SDK about how to do that. Here is an example use:

```
python local_predict.py --input=/path/to/my/local/files --model_dir=/path/to/modeldir.
```

Note that the model_dir points to where the tensorflow meta graph proto and checkpoint files are saved. They are generated by training. Here is the doc link about how to train a model. https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/training-models. The model dir can be on GCS as well.

Thanks for bringing this up. We're continually working to improve the overall experience of the service including error reporting.